# Video error can't be listened on Safari of iOS 8.2

Tags: ios, safari, html5-video, ios8.2

Here is my code snippet:

```
      <video id="myVideo" style="width: 640px; height: 480px; border: solid 1px #ccc;"></video>
      <button onclick="showError()">Click Me</button>
      <script type="text/javascript">
           function showError() {
               console.log('clicked');
               var v = document.getElementById('myVideo');
               v.addEventListener('error',function(e){
                    console.log('>> error happened');
                    },true);
               v.src = 'http://127.0.0.1:9999/test.mp4';
               v.load();
               v.play();
           }
      </script>
```

The video source url is not available, so when click the button , the "error" event should be dispatched. It works on safari of iOS 8.1, but failed on iOS 8.2. Is there any workaround to make it works?

Comment: What happens if you set preload="none" in the video element?

Comment: @aldel I have tried, adding preload attribute is no help.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't read your code carefully enough. I had a theory, but it was wrong.

Comment: Why are you passing true as the third argument to addEventListener (useCapture)?

Comment: @aldel I tried set that argument to false, but it has same result.